# Is there symmetric form for statistical action?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, path-integral, coherent-states

In quantum statistical theory, for a given Hamiltonian $H$, one can express the partition function as

\begin{equation}
   Z = \text{tr}\, e^{-\beta H}
\end{equation}
into the coherent path integral form. In the discrete form, it reads
\begin{equation}
   Z = \int d\phi^{\ast}_1 d\phi_1\int d\phi^{\ast}_2 d\phi_2 ...\int d\phi^{\ast}_M d\phi_M e^{-S[\{\phi_n^{\ast}, \phi_n \}]}.
\end{equation}
For fermion or boson systems, the action usually has the following form,
\begin{eqnarray}
S[\{\phi_n^{\ast}, \phi_n \}]
 =\sum_{n=1}^{M} \phi_{n}^{\ast}(\phi_{n}  - \phi_{n-1} ) + \epsilon \sum_{n=1}^{M} H(c^{\dagger} \rightarrow \phi_{n}^{\ast}, c \rightarrow \phi_{n-1}). 
\end{eqnarray}
where $\epsilon = \beta/M$. $\beta = 1/(kT)$ and $M$ is the number of slices used to discretize $\beta$. Observing the form of $S$, one can notice that it is not symmetric with respect to $\phi_n^{\ast}$ and $\phi_{n-1}$. In particular, the first term (dynamical term) cannot be write down as a quadratic form like $\sum_{m,n} \phi_m^{\ast} A_{mn} \phi_n$ with symmetric matrix $A$.

I know that this is due to the process of doing path integral: when inserting the identity operator into the middle of each pair of $e^{-\epsilon H} e^{-\epsilon H}$, one has to number the coherent state from $1$ to $M$. This process generates such non symmetric form.

My question is that is there any symmetric form of action?
A symmetric form of action is much easier to handle in the problem that I am working on.

Comment: Could you add how you got that form of discrete action? Why is there just one difference of the $\phi$ and not a difference square or a difference also for $\phi^*$?